# How are APL's inner and outer product related?

Tags: operators, apl, dyalog

In APL, one can construct a generalized inner product using `f.g`. According to [the manual](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Operators/Inner%20Product.htm), the result is an array in which each item is constructed from the vectors of the left and right operands as `f/x g¨y` (`x` and `y` being the vectors taken along a specific axis of said operands). On first glance, the outer product looks to be derived from this: it is `∘.g`, which I obtain by setting `f ← ∘`. If I evaluate this using the definition of the inner product, though, I don't seem to get valid APL code (I get `∘/x g¨y`, where `∘/` doesn't make a lot of sense in particular).

Are these two operators related with some magic underneath the hood, or is `∘.` just interpreted as a different operator which has nothing to do with the inner product?

Answer (score 6):

In all modern APLs, including Dyalog, `∘.` is indeed just special-cased, and no left operand to `.` will make it behave like `∘.` — indeed, `∘` is a dyadic operator, which cannot be an operand to another dyadic operator (`.`).

Historically, `∘.g` was seen as a sort of deficient `f.g` since `f.g` can be seen as `f/` over the diagonal values of `∘.g` and thus, removing the reductions' part of the algorithm, an outer product remains. `∘` was used as a sort of "null function", but the symbol was later overloaded to become a regular dyadic (composition) operator.

It is however worth noting that [Iverson](https://apl.wiki/Ken_Iverson) later generalised the outer product in the form of [the "tie" operator](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLDictionary1.htm#dot), where the left operand is a number indicating the number of "tied-up" dimensions, leaving all other dimensions to provide arguments that would be used in all combinations. Thus, `0 .g` became equivalent of `∘.g` and `∘` was defined as a boxed empty vector (essentially equivalent to today's `⊂⍬`) and was treated as `0` when used with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the IBM APL2 language reference (page 165):

```
Z←L LO.RO R   ←→   Z←LO/¨(⊂[ρρL]L)∘.RO ⊂[1]R
```

(where ⎕IO←1 and LO and RO are your functions f and g respectively).